# What's the meaning of "la tramontana" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

The definition I've found is "a northern wind" blowing in Spain, France or Italy.  There's an old Italian song, however, where the word is used and such a definition would make no sense. To my non-native ears, it sounds like some colloquial usage.  The lyrics go something like this:

> Mi piaccion nere, mi piaccion bionde,
>   Mi piaccion tutte le donne al mondo, E per il pizzo di una sottana, Perdo sempre la tramontana. L'ho perduta e la perderò.

PS. Excuse me but my Italian is very poor so I have to write in English.

Comment: It's a very strong cold wind coming from the north, very typical at the northern coastal aerea ([Empordà](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empord%C3%A0)) of my country (Catalonia). You can find some information at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tramontane).

Comment: There are two answers but I'm still waiting for a well-written and coherent answer.

Comment: @Centaurus - in what way the existing  posts  do not answer your question? The expression you need to understand is the metaphor "perdere la tramontana" which is quite an old saying. That is what the song is about.

Comment: @xxxxxx  I appreciate the efforts to answer my question, I could understand what they tried to explain and I have upvoted both answers.  I don't think, however, they are well-written and some sentences like "In this case tramontana is employed metaphorically to indicate the North" just don't fit.

Comment: @Centaurus - I am probably missing the point you want to make. The tramontana, be it a wind or a star, is a metaphor for orientation which, if  you lose it, you are at a loss, you don't know where to go or what to do. This metaphorical sense is used only in   the  saying  "perdere la la tramontana", you would not say "I am looking for the tramontana, or I found the tramontana", it is a set phrase, a proverb which the song used in its lyrics. What is that you still don't understand?

Comment: Centaurus, I believe you have now all the information to write an answer yourself, exactly phrased the way you deem it should be.

Comment: Given your interest in the song, I post a link that put the song, its lyrics and those who wrote and sang it in the context of those years. Hope it helps: http://karahidden.blogspot.com/2011/01/la-tramontana-storia-della-canzone.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The song you are referring to is  [La tramontana](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt38kYDLVWk), sung by *Antoine* in 1968, actually a French singer.

According to the following source "la tramontana" in ancient times, before the compass was invented, was used by sailors to refer to the North Star. When the star was not clearly visible sailors could easily lose their way. This may be the origin of modern usage of "***perdere  la tramontana***" that is lose one's way or figuratively, be at a loss, not know what to do.

> - Prima dell'invenzione della bussola, i naviganti chiamavano tramontana la stella polare. Quando essa non era visibile a causa del cielo nuvoloso, l'orientamento era impossibile. Forse è in relazione a ciò che il detto citato viene riferito a chi non sa cosa fare. [Proverbi](http://www.proverbi-italiani.com/cerca-75-P.html)

I'd add that the expression is dated and is not commonly used nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  As for the singer, actually I heard it sung by GIANNI PETTENATI, an Italian.

Comment: @Centaurus - yes, the song was actually sung by both singers at the Sanremo Festival in 1968. https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_tramontana

Answer (score 5):

From the [dizionario Treccani, *tramontana*, meaning 2](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tramontana/)

> *perdere la tramontana*, lo stesso che perdere la bussola, disorientarsi, confondersi, o perdere il controllo di sé.

That is in English

> *perdere la tramontana*, the same as *perdere la bussola*, losing the direction or losing one's self control

In this case *tramontana* is employed to indicate the North, that is the direction this wind blows from.

Comment: That's curious because in Catalan we often say of people from Empordà that they are "tocats per la tramuntana", literally meaning that they are "touched by Tramontane", with the sense that they are suffering some kind of negative effects popularly associated to this wind which can even make them a little bit softheaded.

Comment: I disagree with "In this case tramontana is employed metaphorically to indicate the North".   From the explanations and definitions I've read, it is clear that "tramontana" literally means "a northern wind" or "coming from the north".  It's in the song that "tramontana" is used metaphorically.

Comment: @Centaurus - the saying "***perdere la tramontana***" existed well before the song was written.

Comment: @Centaurus: It's a metaphoric use in the sense that it's not referring to geographic north.

Comment: @Centaurus Ok I expressed myself slightly imprecisely. It is a *metonymy* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), mentioning the wind to mean the direction it blows from, similar to *lend me the ear*, where you do not physically detach the ear to give it to the speaker. Here you do not "lose" the wind (whatever that would mean), but its direction.

Comment: And in fact, there is also a metaphor on top of that, as Charo says, where you say *I lost the North* to mean *I lost control of myself*.

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood my comment.  I said that when "la tramontana" refers to "a nothern wind" it's the **literal** meaning of the word.  Then again, in the phrase "perdere la tramontana"  tramontana is used **metaphorically.** @xxxxxx no matter whether the expression antedates the song or not.

Comment: @Centaurus I think I don't understand you. Are you saying that *a northern wind* and *the direction North* are literally the same thing? I am not saying I am right, but I honestly do not understand your objections. If you could clear it maybe I can improve this answer to your satisfaction. To restate my position: *tramontana* is a name for the direction North, and I consider this usage a metonymy, in the same way you could say that someone is "coming from the sunrise" to mean that s/he comes from the east.

Comment: @DenisNardin  Please read my last comment again.  It all about "literal" versus "metaphorical".   "Tramontana" the northern wind, is the literal meaning of the word. "Perdere la Tramontana",  contrary to what your answer says, is the metaphorical use.

Comment: @Centaurus I agree that the wind is the literal meaning of the word. The word also (metaphorically) means the direction North. I think that's what I am saying in the answer and I do not understand what are you disagreeing with

Comment: I'm saying that the only metaphorical meaning is the idiomatic phrase "perdere la tramontana".  Both the wind and the north direction are literal meanings.

Comment: I think we will have to agree to disagree on that (with the aforementioned caveat that it is more precisely a metonymy rather then a metaphor)

Comment: I am going to remove the offending word *metaphorically* but I consider the second meaning (the North direction) a derived meaning. Also I consider extremely pointless to spend time discussing what *literal meaning* exactly means, so I'm not going to take part to this discussion, which is bloated and unduly long anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Nel contesto della frase perdere la Tramontana significa (come modo di dire) perdere la testa.

In English:

- lose your head
- out of mind

Comment: Di certo non “letteralmente”.

Comment: Svista mia. Già corretto

Comment: Grazie, @momomorez! :)